# Bluetooth module JDY-08 not finding Android device

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have 1 JDY-08 MASTER that scans looking for myDeviceName and triggers a function when it finds that device name.

```
String get_ble_scan_data(void){

    String  final_result = "";
    String result = "";//reset and declare
    String extract = set_ble("AT+SCAN1");//scan for device name, signal strength and mac address
    String extract2 = set_ble("AT+GETDCD");//get number of device found

    //now we are going to check for which extraction has the data we interested in
    if((extract.length() > threshold or extract.length() > threshold)){

      result = extract;//pass extract as result
      if(extract2.length() > extract.length()){//check which is bigger
        result = extract2;//pass extract2 as result if its bigger in length than extract
        }
      }

    if(result.length() > 0){//add filter and execution here
      String filter = result;//copy
      result = "";// reset
      while(filter.indexOf('=') > -1){// we use the char = as a seperator

        filter = filter.substring(filter.indexOf('=') + 1);//remove strings before seperator
        result += filter.substring(0, filter.indexOf('\n')) + ' '; //extract till newline character
        filter = filter.substring(filter.indexOf(result) + result.length());//remove extracted result so we go on to next extraction of same result if there is more device picked up
         detect
        }

      result.trim();//remove spaces at the end or start if any

      final_result = result;

    }

  return final_result;

}

void ble_response(String search_result){

  String scan_result = search_result;//do bluetooth scan
  if(scan_result.indexOf(myDeviceName) > -1 ){//when data present in scan and it contains desired key
  if(scan_result.indexOf(' ') == -1){//if only one ble is picked up

    ble_macaddress = scan_result.substring(0, scan_result.indexOf(','));
    scan_result = scan_result.substring(scan_result.indexOf(ble_macaddress) + 1 + ble_macaddress.length(), scan_result.length());//remove mac address
    ble_strength = scan_result.substring(0, scan_result.indexOf(','));
    ble_name = scan_result.substring(scan_result.indexOf(ble_strength) + 1 + ble_strength.length(), scan_result.length());//remove mac address

    if(((int) ble_strength.toFloat()) >= trigger_threshold and ble_name == key){

      trigger_action();
    }
  }else{//if multiple ble is picked up

    String cut = "";
    while(scan_result.indexOf(',') > -1){//while there is still result to be processed

      cut = scan_result.substring(0, scan_result.indexOf(' '));
      scan_result = scan_result.substring(scan_result.indexOf(cut) + 1 + cut.length(), scan_result.length());
      if(cut.indexOf(myDeviceName) > -1){//only analyze if it contains key

        ble_macaddress = cut.substring(0, cut.indexOf(','));
        cut = cut.substring(cut.indexOf(ble_macaddress) + 1 + ble_macaddress.length(), cut.length());//remove mac address
        ble_strength = cut.substring(0, cut.indexOf(','));
        ble_name = cut.substring(cut.indexOf(ble_strength) + 1 + ble_strength.length(), cut.length());//remove mac address

        if(((int) ble_strength.toFloat()) >= trigger_threshold and ble_name == key){

         trigger_action();
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I use another JDY-08 device with one button, It finds the device and triggers the action:

```
if(!digitalRead(11)){//if button is pushed///////

      delay(500);
      set_ble("AT+NAMEmyDeviceName");//change ble name
      while(!digitalRead(11));//do nothing while button is still pressed
      delay(2000);//allow time before name change back
      set_ble("AT+NAMEJDY-08");//change name back
```

But when I use the phone It doesn´t trigger the action:

```
private void advertise(){
        final BluetoothLeAdvertiser advertiser = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBluetoothLeAdvertiser();
        final AdvertiseSettings settings = new AdvertiseSettings.Builder()
                .setAdvertiseMode( AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_LATENCY )
                .setTxPowerLevel( AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_HIGH )
                .setConnectable( true )
                .build();

        final AdvertiseData data = new AdvertiseData.Builder()
                .setIncludeDeviceName( true )
                .build();

        final AdvertiseCallback advertisingCallback = new AdvertiseCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStartSuccess(AdvertiseSettings settingsInEffect) {
                super.onStartSuccess(settingsInEffect);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartFailure(int errorCode) {
                Log.e( "BLE", "Advertising onStartFailure: " + errorCode );
                super.onStartFailure(errorCode);
            }
        };
        advertiser.startAdvertising(settings,data,advertisingCallback);

        final Handler myTimerHandler = new Handler();
        myTimerHandler.postDelayed(
                new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        advertiser.stopAdvertising(advertisingCallback);
                    }
                } , 30000);
    }
```

I also use the intent with BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE.

Using NRFConnect app, I can see how the JDY-08 Button device changes the device name (That triggers the action on the JDY-08 MASTER). I can also see the Android device with myDeviceName but this does not trigger the action. Am I missing something in the Android app?

Comment: You want to trigger an action on your JDY-08 Master as soon as it detects your android phone?

Comment: Yes, as soon as it detects the android phone with myDeviceName.

Comment: You said _I can also see the Android device with myDeviceName but this does not trigger the action._ Where do you see myDeviceName? Have you tried adding a debug output to `void ble_response(String search_result)` to see what devices get picked up and with which signal strength

Comment: I can see it in NRFConnect app. I see both with myDeviceName but only the JDY-08 triggers the action. I don´t know how to debug on the JDY-08 MASTER, I was given the task to make the phone change its name to myDeviceName being SLAVE, as the JDY-08 is looking for SLAVES with myDeviceName.

Comment: Where does `ble_response()`run? On the JDY-Master itself or on a microcontroller (arduino, etc) to which the JDY-Master is connected to?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I´m trying to find out where is that code running.

Comment: Please answer your own question in case someone else comes across the same issue in the future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the JDY-Master only received the name of JDY devices. All other devices show mac address and signal strength only.